# Pinescprit-How to color lines?

Tags: pine-script

i just began programming with pinescript and find it very complicated.
I programmed the little indicator below, which should show some fibo lines on a 15 minute chart.
The range of the last 15 minute range gets multiplicated with the fibonacci numbers 0.382 and 0.618.
The results get added or substracted to the next 15 min open.
The problem is, that i cannot put color to the indicator lines. 
My questions:
 1. Why "**plot(highrange1,color.color.red)**" does not work?
 2. What is the difference between "**tickerid" and syminfo.tickerid**"
 3. How is it possible to avoid a connection between the lines (each 15 min line should not be  connected to the one before)?

```
    '''**study(title="Fibobreak", shorttitle="Fibobreak", overlay=true) 
    range = high - low
    a=range[1]*0.382
    b=range[1]*0.618
    h=open+a
    h1=open+b
    l=open-a
    l1=open-b
    highrange1 = security(tickerid, '15', h) 
    highrange2 = security(tickerid, '15', h1) 
    lowrange1 = security(tickerid, '15', l) 
    lowrange2 = security(tickerid, '15', l1) 
    plot(highrange1,color.color.red)
    plot(highrange2)
    plot(lowrange1)
    plot(lowrange2)**'''
```

Would appriciate your help very much.

Comment: Perhaps format your question a little bit better, and add some sample screenshot to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

answers as per your questions:

1. Two things. First, you need to have the `//@version=4` comment before starting in order for the colors to be recognized with text aliases. Second, we must assigned values with an equal signal when passing arguments to functions
2. See [tickerid here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_tickerid) and [syminfo.tickerid here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dtickerid) (Links to the reference manual)
3. Not clear what you mean, it does not look like the lines are connected.

The code below should do the trick. Try it out and let us know ;)

```
//@version=4
study(title="Fibobreak", shorttitle="Fibobreak", overlay=true) 
range = high - low
a=range[1]*0.382
b=range[1]*0.618
h=open+a
h1=open+b
l=open-a
l1=open-b
highrange1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', h) 
highrange2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', h1) 
lowrange1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', l) 
lowrange2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', l1) 
plot(highrange1,color=color.red)
plot(highrange2)
plot(lowrange1)
plot(lowrange2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works. But the there is still a vertical line connection between the lines. It should look this way:        ______
                                                         m                 _____

Comment: Hello,
i use a similar code for thinkorswim and noticed that on tradingview the lines seem to be displaced by15 min to the right. In thinkorswim the indicator is displayed correctly.

Comment: I have shortened the code that way:
//@version=4
study(title="Fibobreak", shorttitle="Fibobreak", overlay=true) 
range = security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', high[1]) -security(syminfo.tickerid, '15', low[1]) 
a=range*0.382
b=range*0.618
h=open+a
h1=open+b
l=open-a
l1=open-b
plot(h,color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(h1,color=color.orange,linewidth=2)
plot(l,color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(l1,color=color.lime,linewidth=2)'''

Comment: Hi, I don't see any vertical line connection between the lines. For me what I've sent you works fine, and the shortened one above, from you, works just as well with no vertical line nowhere.